# Matlab: deleted subversion repository

Tags: matlab, svn, restart, delete-directory

I use the *subversion* functionality, which is built into *matlab*. It worked fine till my colleague deleted the *repository* (not the sandbox). Now nothing is working.

I tried to set up an other repository. However, if I tried to *add* a file, matlab complains. So I wonder, how I can reset *subversion* in order to get a fresh start. I don't care, if all the old *check outs* are lost -- my priority is to get subversion back, as fast as possible.

Cheers,
Jonas

Comment: Do you ask about repository or working copy? Working copy is located on your workstation, repository is located on the server. What does matlab complain about? What's the error?

Comment: He delete the repository, not the _working copy_. The error text reads: "Could not add files: svn: E150000: Can't find parent directory's node while trying to add XYZ.m"